# Compiler not showing error on declaring pointer of undefined type

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, declaration

I compiled the following c code using gcc compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node{
        int info;
        struct test* next;
};

int main()
{
        struct node start;
        struct node* p;
        start.info = 2;
        start.next = (struct test*)&start;
        printf("start.next = %p \n",start.next);
        p = start.next;
        printf("p->info = %d\n",p->info);
}
```

But to my surprise, after declaring `next`(in `structure node`) as a pointer to an undeclared type(`struct test`), still the compilation is successful !!! After compilation of the above program its printing only a warning as follows:

```
test.c:15:4: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  p = start.next;
    ^
```

Now my doubt is why the compiler did not produced an error for not declaring `structure test` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no undefined types in your program. There is an incomplete type `struct test` declared within structure `struct node`.
You may use pointers to incomplete types.

That it would be more clear consider a simplified example

```
struct node{
        int info;
        struct node* next;
};
```

Within this structure pointer next also points to incomplete type `struct node` because the structure definition will be completed only after the closing brace.

A more interesting example. Type `void *` is used very othen in C programs. However according to the C Standard (6.2.5 Types, p.#19)

> 19 The void type comprises an empty set of values; **it is an
>   incomplete object type** that cannot be completed.

As for pointers themselves then  (C Standard, 6.2.5 Types, p.#21)

```
A pointer type is a complete object type.
```

And about the structures themselves (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers, p.#8)

> 8 The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a
>   struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type, within a translation
>   unit. The struct-declaration-list is a sequence of declarations for
>   the members of the structure or union. If the struct-declaration-list
>   contains no named members, no anonymous structures, and no anonymous
>   unions, the behavior is undefined. **The type is incomplete until
>   immediately after the } that terminates the list, and complete
>   thereafter**.

Answer (score 1):

Under the [explicit type conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) section from cppreference:

> In addition, C-style cast notation is allowed to cast from, to, and
>   between pointers to incomplete class type. If both expression and
>   new_type are pointers to incomplete class types, it's unspecified
>   whether static_cast or reinterpret_cast gets selected.

`struct test*` is a pointer to an incomplete type. `struct test` is a forward declaration that's being introduced into the local scope of main.